# F4 Menu in DarkRP Server will not work

Tags: garrys-mod

I am creating a DarkRP server with the latest version of Garry's Mod. I am attempting to enable and use the default jobs on the server, but I get this error in the client console whenever I press F4:

```
[DarkRP] gamemodes/darkrp/gamemode/modules/base/cl_gamemode_functions.lua:23: attempt to index local 'jobTable' (a nil value)
  1. Call - gamemodes/darkrp/gamemode/modules/base/cl_gamemode_functions.lua:23
   2. unknown - gamemodes/darkrp/gamemode/modules/base/cl_gamemode_functions.lua:62
```

This is the `cl_gamemode_functions.lua` file:

```
local GUIToggled = false
local mouseX, mouseY = ScrW() / 2, ScrH() / 2
function GM:ShowSpare1()
    local jobTable = LocalPlayer():getJobTable()

    if jobTable.ShowSpare1 then
        return jobTable.ShowSpare1(LocalPlayer())
    end

    GUIToggled = not GUIToggled

    if GUIToggled then
        gui.SetMousePos(mouseX, mouseY)
    else
        mouseX, mouseY = gui.MousePos()
    end
    gui.EnableScreenClicker(GUIToggled)
end

function GM:ShowSpare2()
    local jobTable = LocalPlayer():getJobTable()

    if jobTable.ShowSpare2 then
        return jobTable.ShowSpare2(LocalPlayer())
    end

    DarkRP.toggleF4Menu()
end

function GM:PlayerStartVoice(ply)
    if ply == LocalPlayer() then
        ply.DRPIsTalking = true
        return -- Not the original rectangle for yourself! ugh!
    end
    self.Sandbox.PlayerStartVoice(self, ply)
end

function GM:PlayerEndVoice(ply)
    if ply == LocalPlayer() then
        ply.DRPIsTalking = false
        return
    end

    self.Sandbox.PlayerEndVoice(self, ply)
end

function GM:OnPlayerChat()
end

local FKeyBinds = {
    ["gm_showhelp"] = "ShowHelp",
    ["gm_showteam"] = "ShowTeam",
    ["gm_showspare1"] = "ShowSpare1",
    ["gm_showspare2"] = "ShowSpare2"
}

function GM:PlayerBindPress(ply, bind, pressed)
    self.Sandbox.PlayerBindPress(self, ply, bind, pressed)

    local bnd = string.match(string.lower(bind), "gm_[a-z]+[12]?")
    if bnd and FKeyBinds[bnd] then
        hook.Call(FKeyBinds[bnd], GAMEMODE)
    end

    if not self.Config.deadvoice and not ply:Alive() and string.find(string.lower(bind), "voicerecord") then return true end
end

function GM:InitPostEntity()
    hook.Call("teamChanged", GAMEMODE, GAMEMODE.DefaultTeam, GAMEMODE.DefaultTeam)
end

function GM:teamChanged(before, after)
end

local function OnChangedTeam(um)
    local oldTeam, newTeam = um:ReadShort(), um:ReadShort()
    hook.Call("teamChanged", GAMEMODE, oldTeam, newTeam) -- backwards compatibility
    hook.Call("OnPlayerChangedTeam", GAMEMODE, LocalPlayer(), oldTeam, newTeam)
end
usermessage.Hook("OnChangedTeam", OnChangedTeam)

timer.Simple(0, function() GAMEMODE.ShowTeam = DarkRP.openKeysMenu end)
```

Comment: Can you post the original code? Or the lines that the error is referring to?

Comment: @BritishFerret I am assuming [this](https://github.com/FPtje/DarkRP/blob/master/gamemode/modules/base/cl_gamemode_functions.lua) is the file in question.

Comment: @JAL That is the file.

Comment: I attached the code in the cl_gamemode_functions.lua file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These questions assume you are using the codebase at [FPtje/DarkRP](https://github.com/FPtje/DarkRP).

A few ideas.

- You have a corrupt `jobTable` database. ([Source](https://github.com/FPtje/DarkRP/issues/2461))
- You are trying to load the game mode in single player. (Same source as above)
- You are trying to modify the cl_gamemode_functions.lua file directly without using an addon like [darkrpmodification](https://github.com/FPtje/darkrpmodification). ([Source](https://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1508073))
- You created or joined an invalid team. ([Source](https://github.com/FPtje/DarkRP/issues/2331))
- You are trying to call a gamemode function that before the gamemode has finished setting up. ([Source](https://github.com/FPtje/DarkRP/issues/2306))

Comment: I don't know if I have a corrupt jobTable database, I am launching into the server from the browser (not legacy), I am usign darkrpmodification, I cannot join a team to begin with and thrown into Joining/Connection, and I have not modified the file so I do not know if that code is messing it up (I attached the code in cl_gamemode_functions.lua above).

Comment: You also don't have to supply sources everytime.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow I provided the links to open issues on GitHub because I thought they would help.  Have you thought about opening your own issue on the repo?

Comment: I managed to fix my issue. Since you seem to have knowledge on server hosting, I am still having other errors unrelated to my question. Players keep spawning in walls and they cannot use weapons or see the HUD to select one.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow maybe ask a new question?  I'm not sure what could be wrong.